# Why does git sometimes show conflicts when there is actually nothing to do

Tags: git, conflict

Sometimes git encounters conflicts in a file. However, if I look at the conflict with TortoiseMerge, which I usually use to resolve them, it shows no conflicts. It does show changes but it doesn't show any conflicts. In case this happens I just click on "Mark as resolved"

This works but I just wonder why git marked the file as conflicted in the first place?

Comment: I guess there could be a file permission conflict, for instance if you have marked a file as executable (755) and a file is checked out as 644

Comment: I'm on windows. Not sure what should cause file permissions to change. I mean, there are changes in that file. It's just that there are no conflicts or at least nothing that TortoiseMerge consider as a conflict.

Comment: Ugh, git on windows is an evil thing. I've close to given it up after countless unexplained corrupted git folders and other bugs

Comment: When did you last try it? It's actually super stable for me. It's really just this random occurrence of those inexplicable conflicts that bother me from time to time. However, I don't even know if that's a windows thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you met file permission problem in win, you can config:

git config file.mode false

This will ignore file mode problem.

Br,
Tim